# I am sending data from customactivity to activity js code but the payload body request is not getting set

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity

> Also, when i debugged it, the req.body in getting error - <Buffer 65
> 79 4a 30 65 58 41 69 4f 69 4a 4b 56 31 51 69 4c 43 4a 68 62 47 63 69
> 4f 69 4a 49 55 7a 49 31 4e 69 4a 39 2e 65 77 30 4b 49 43 41 69 61 57
> 35 42 63 ... >

```
   congig.json
```

```
{
    "workflowApiVersion": "1.1",
    "metaData": {
        "icon": "images/icon.png",
        "iconSmall": "images/iconSmall.png",
        "category": "message"
    },
    "type": "REST",
    "lang": {
        "en-US": {
            "name": "Nexmo",
          "description": "SMS.",
          "step1Label": "Nexmo"
        }
    },
    "arguments": {
        "execute": {
           "inArguments":[
             {
          "phone": "{{Contact.Attribute.DEActivity.Phone}}"
        },
        {
                  "emailAddress": "{{Contact.Attribute.DEActivity.EmailAddress}}"
                }                                       
            ],
          "outArguments": [],
          "url": "https://urltest.herokuapp.com/journeybuilder/execute",
           "verb": "POST",
            "body": "",
            "header": "",
            "format": "json",
            "useJwt": true,
            "timeout": 2000
        }
    },
    "configurationArguments": {
      "applicationExtensionKey": "xxxxxx",
      "save": {
        "url": "https://urltest.herokuapp.com/journeybuilder/save",
          "verb": "POST",
        "useJwt": true
       },
       "publish": {
        "url": "https://urltest.herokuapp.com/journeybuilder/publish",
           "verb": "POST",
        "useJwt": true
       },
      "validate": {
        "url": "https://urltest.herokuapp.com/journeybuilder/validate",
        "verb": "POST",
        "useJwt": true
      }
    },
    "wizardSteps": [
        { "label": "Configure Activity", "key": "step1" }
    ],
    "userInterfaces": {
        "configModal": {
            "height": 400,
            "width": 1000,
          "fullscreen": false
        }
    },
    "schema": {
        "arguments": {
            "execute": {
                "inArguments": [],
                "outArguments": []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
   index.html
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/require.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.6/require.min.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            var config = {
                baseUrl: 'js'
            };

            var dependencies = [
                'customActivity'
            ];

            require(config, dependencies);
        })();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="step1" class="step">
        <div class="slds-grid">

            <main class="slds-col">
               
                <h1>welcome to your activity!</h1>
            </main>
            
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
   activity.js
```

```
'use strict';
var util = require('util');

// Deps
const Path = require('path');
const JWT = require(Path.join(__dirname, '..', 'lib', 'jwtDecoder.js'));
var util = require('util');
var http = require('https');
//const Nexmo = require('nexmo');
//var axios = require('axios');
//const Vonage = require('@vonage/server-sdk');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const Nexmo = require('nexmo');
//const socketio = require('socket.io');


exports.logExecuteData = [];

function logData(req) {
    exports.logExecuteData.push({
        body: req.body,
        headers: req.headers,
        trailers: req.trailers,
        method: req.method,
        url: req.url,
        params: req.params,
        query: req.query,
        route: req.route,
        cookies: req.cookies,
        ip: req.ip,
        path: req.path,
        host: req.host,
        fresh: req.fresh,
        stale: req.stale,
        protocol: req.protocol,
        secure: req.secure,
        originalUrl: req.originalUrl
    });
    console.log("body: " + util.inspect(req.body));
    console.log("headers: " + req.headers);
    console.log("trailers: " + req.trailers);
    console.log("method: " + req.method);
    console.log("url: " + req.url);
    console.log("params: " + util.inspect(req.params));
    console.log("query: " + util.inspect(req.query));
    console.log("route: " + req.route);
    console.log("cookies: " + req.cookies);
    console.log("ip: " + req.ip);
    console.log("path: " + req.path);
    console.log("host: " + req.host);
    console.log("fresh: " + req.fresh);
    console.log("stale: " + req.stale);
    console.log("protocol: " + req.protocol);
    console.log("secure: " + req.secure);
    console.log("originalUrl: " + req.originalUrl);
}

/*
 * POST Handler for / route of Activity (this is the edit route).
 */
exports.edit = function (req, res) {
    // Data from the req and put it in an array accessible to the main app.
    //console.log( req.body );
    logData(req);
    //res.send(200, 'Edit');
    res.status(200).send('Edit');
};

/*
 * POST Handler for /save/ route of Activity.
 */
exports.save = function (req, res) {
    // Data from the req and put it in an array accessible to the main app.
    console.log( req.body );
    logData(req);
    //res.send(200, 'Save');
    res.status(200).send('Save');
};

/*
 * POST Handler for /execute/ route of Activity.
 */
exports.execute = function (req, res) {

    console.log("For Execute"); 
    
  
JWT(req.body, process.env.jwtSecret, (err, decoded) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return res.status(401).end();
  }
  if (decoded && decoded.inArguments && decoded.inArguments.length > 0) {
    var decodedArgs = decoded.inArguments[0];
    logData(decodedArgs.body); //here i am getting buffer as o/p
    // do something
  }else {
    console.error('inArguments invalid.');
    return res.status(400).end();
  }
});

  
    //var requestBody = req.body.inArguments[0];

    logData(req);
    res.status(200).send('Execute');

  
};


/*
 * POST Handler for /publish/ route of Activity.
 */
exports.publish = function (req, res) {
    // Data from the req and put it in an array accessible to the main app.
    //console.log( req.body );
    logData(req);
    //res.send(200, 'Publish');
    res.status(200).send('Publish');

};

/*
 * POST Handler for /validate/ route of Activity.
 */
exports.validate = function (req, res) {
    // Data from the req and put it in an array accessible to the main app.
    //console.log( req.body );
    logData(req);
    //res.send(200, 'Validate');
    res.status(200).send('Validate');
};
```

```
   customActivity.js
```

```
define([
    'postmonger'
], function (
    Postmonger
) {
    'use strict';

    var connection = new Postmonger.Session();
    var authTokens = {};
    //var authTokens ;
    var payload = {};
    $(window).ready(onRender);

    connection.on('initActivity', initialize);
    connection.on('requestedTokens', onGetTokens);
    connection.on('requestedEndpoints', onGetEndpoints);

    connection.on('clickedNext', save);
   
    
    function onRender() {
        // JB will respond the first time 'ready' is called with 'initActivity'
        connection.trigger('ready');

        connection.trigger('requestTokens');
        connection.trigger('requestEndpoints');

    }

    function initialize(data) {
        console.log("INITACTIVITY INITACTIVITY INITACTIVITY INITACTIVITY INITACTIVITY ");
        console.log(data);
        if (data) {
            payload = data;
        }
        
        var hasInArguments = Boolean(
            payload['arguments'] &&
            payload['arguments'].execute &&
            payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments &&
            payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments.length > 0
        );

        var inArguments = hasInArguments ? payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments : {};
        console.log("INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS ");
        console.log(inArguments);
        console.log("INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS INARGS ");

//        console.log(inArguments);

        $.each(inArguments, function (index, inArgument) {
            $.each(inArgument, function (key, val) {
                
              
            });
        });

        connection.trigger('updateButton', {
             button: 'next',
            text: 'done',
            visible: true
        });
    }

    function onGetTokens(tokens) {
        console.log("Tokens function: "+JSON.stringify(tokens));
        console.log(tokens);
        authTokens = tokens;
    }

    function onGetEndpoints(endpoints) {
        console.log("Get End Points function: "+JSON.stringify(endpoints));
        console.log(endpoints);
    }

    function save() {
        console.log("Save Save Save Save Save Save"); 

      /*  payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [{
            "tokens": authTokens,
            "emailAddress": "{{Contact.Attribute.DECustom.EmailAddress}}",
            "phone": "{{Contact.Attribute.DECustom.Phone}}"
        }];
        
*/

        payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [{
            "tokens": authTokens,
            "emailAddress": "test@test.com",
            "phone": "91XXXXXXXXXX"
           
        }];
    

        payload['metaData'].isConfigured = true;

        console.log(payload);
        console.log("payload: "+JSON.stringify(payload));
        console.log(tokens);
        

        connection.trigger('updateActivity', payload);
    }



    
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please [edit] to add as much detail about the problem as you can (a block of code is usually not enough) and show only the relevant code in your post. This helps the community, and you, identify the issue more effectively.

Comment: Please use the tools in the editor to format your post, including code blocks (the `{}` tool), and please include _only the code needed to reproduce the problem_.

Comment: Hey David, Thanks for the help. I have edited the code and posted it again.

Comment: Can you update your execute method in the activity.js file to make it more clear which section is logging the data to the console. That response is a buffer and not an error code. Also, you should try logging your decodedArgs variable to the console as that's your actual payload.

Comment: Hey Jason, I have updated the activity.js